# How do I prove that a subset is closed in the topological space of $n \times n$-matrices.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Consider the topological space $M$ of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology.  Let $\mathcal{A} \subset M$ be the set of matrices such that $det(A) = 1$ for $ A \in \mathcal{A}$. I need to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subset of $M$.

But I am unsure of my approach towards a proof. Could anyone be kind enough to comment on my approach

The following is my idea of a proof.

To show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subset of $M$,we need to show $M \setminus A$ is open in $M$. Take an element $m \in M \setminus A$. Note that $det(m) \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$ which is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. As the determinant operation is a continuous function, so $det^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}) = M \setminus A$ is open in $M$. Hence, $A$ is a closed subset of $M$.

One of the problems I have is with the statement about determinant being a continuous function. With the special case of $2\times2$ matrices, we can define projection maps for each of the entries in a matrix. As the projection maps are continuous, products and sums ( difference ) of them are continuous. Hence, the determinant is continuous. But I am not sure how I can generalise this to the case of $n \times n$-matrices ?

I thank you for your time and help.

**Edit:** I now understand the continuity of the determinant. Would anyone be kind enough to comment on the proof.

Comment: $\det:M_n(\mathbb{R})\equiv \mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial function and so continuous.

Comment: Of course! The characteristic polynomial! I am ashamed I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We prove the continuity of the $\det$ function by two ways:

- for $A=(a_{i,j})$ we have

$$\det (A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\epsilon(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\sigma(k)}$$
so we see that the determinant is a polynomial function on its entries so it's continuous

- the determinant is a multilinear function on a finite dimensional linear space so it's continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would it also be possible for you to comment on the proof ? Thank you.